# Swapping keys for cesium mouse events and creating custom events

Tags: mouseevent, mouse, default, swap, cesiumjs

I am new to cesium so need some very basic help.

How can we swap the behavior of the mouse left button and right button without having to code the behavior ourselves?

Moreover, can someone give me a basic coding example to define our own mouse button event? I have tried to run the one from Sandcastle but it is not working at the moment, can't figure out the problem for now.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, give us a code example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Cesium's mouse event system, you can just listen to the normal JavaScript mouse events outside of Cesium and react to them.  The DOM element to listen to is the canvas, typically `viewer.cesiumWidget.canvas`.

Cesium's built-in event system is not easily configurable for now, that's an item on the wishlist.  Part of the problem here is that the default behavior changes at runtime.  For example, when the camera tracks or un-tracks an entity, the input event wiring gets rearranged on the fly, and customizations may be overwritten.  Someday Cesium's event handlers will need to be rewritten to be configurable.

Answer (score 1):

To extend what @emackey stated:

The general recommendation from the Cesium team is to use native JS events whenever possible.  The event handlers within the Cesium library are there more for internal library use and plugin modules.

As for how to capture the mouse click/scroll/move events otherwise it would be helpful to have an example of what you tried so far.  Though this is a good reference to read http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/